# Optimize the python function with numpy without using the for loop

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following python function:

```
def npnearest(u: np.ndarray, X: np.ndarray, Y: np.ndarray, distance: 'callbale'=npdistance):
    '''
    Finds x1 so that x1 is in X and u and x1 have a minimal distance (according to the 
    provided distance function) compared to all other data points in X. Returns the label of x1

    Args:
        u (np.ndarray): The vector (ndim=1) we want to classify
        X (np.ndarray): A matrix (ndim=2) with training data points (vectors)
        Y (np.ndarray): A vector containing the label of each data point in X
        distance (callable): A function that receives two inputs and defines the distance function used

    Returns:
        int: The label of the data point which is closest to `u`
    '''

    xbest = None
    ybest = None
    dbest = float('inf')

    for x, y in zip(X, Y):
        d = distance(u, x)
        if d < dbest:
            ybest = y
            xbest = x
            dbest = d

    return ybest
```

Where, `npdistance` simply gives distance between two points i.e.

```
def npdistance(x1, x2):
    return(np.sum((x1-x2)**2))
```

I want to optimize `npnearest` by performing nearest neighbor search directly in `numpy`. This means that the function cannot use `for/while` loops.

Thanks

Comment: Do you **have** to use that `npdistance` function?

Comment: no I don't need to really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't need to use that exact function, you can simply change the sum to work over a particular axis. This will return a new list with the calculations and you can call `argmin` to get the index of the minimum value. Use that and lookup your label:

```
import numpy as np

def npdistance_idx(x1, x2):
    return np.argmin(np.sum((x1-x2)**2, axis=1))

Y = ["label 0", "label 1", "label 2", "label 3"]
u = np.array([[1, 5.5]])
X = np.array([[1,2], [1, 5], [0, 0], [7, 7]])

idx = npdistance_idx(X,  u)
print(Y[idx])  # label 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this works but somehow this is slower than the python version? [This](https://imgur.com/a/kz9HaMg) is the time plot. This should not be happening, right?

Comment: @BlueMango not sure how you're getting those results. When I test it with an X of just 300 pairs, the numpy version is `20.8 µs ± 543 ns per loop` vs `2.47 ms ± 25.8 µs per loop` for the loop. The difference only increases as the array grows.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy supports vectorized operations ([broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/theory.broadcasting.html#array-broadcasting-in-numpy))

This means you can pass in arrays and operations will be applied to entire arrays in an optimized way (SIMD - single instruction, multiple data)

You can then get the address of the array minimum using `.argmin()`

Hope this helps

```py
In [9]: numbers = np.arange(10); numbers                                                                                                        
Out[9]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [10]: numbers -= 5; numbers                                                                                                                  
Out[10]: array([-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4])

In [11]: numbers = np.power(numbers, 2); numbers                                                                                                
Out[11]: array([25, 16,  9,  4,  1,  0,  1,  4,  9, 16])

In [12]: numbers.argmin()                                                                                                                       
Out[12]: 5
```